# hashids: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, unique-id

The following gives me an issue saying `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

```
var Hashids = require('hashids'), hashids = new Hashids('my salt', 8);
```

I am using this [hashids.js](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.js.) class.

The description says that this is a client-side version of Node.js version. I am not using bower so I just load the `hashids.js` on the page.

Are there any other javascript files I need to have this `hashids.js` is dependent on?

How do I get it working?

Comment: `require.js` is supported since `1.0.1` version onwards. Removing `require('hashids')` will make it work alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use node code in client-side unless you use library like browserify to load the module.

Try this instead -> https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.js/blob/master/lib/hashids.js